# Foundation - show content for all tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, zurb-foundation

I have made a website that shows alot of results. These can then be filtered using tabs. This works great for showing just a section of my content.
The problem is now that I want a tab called "Show all" which shows all the content of all tabs.
My first ideas was to simply show them and then hide the aria-hidden attribute.

```
$('.tabs-content div').removeAttr('aria-hidden');
$('.tabs-content div').show();
```

It seems to work at first as the "Show all" tab is selected and all content is shown. The issue is that it breaks the rest of the tabs until I refresh. I have also tried using this but this does not work either.

```
$(document).foundation('tab', 'reflow');
```

My last ideas was to output the content again inside a new content section, but this seems dumb.

Any ideas on how to do this without breaking foundation and without loading all content x2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you already found a solution. For others having this question, this should work:

Add a `id="all` to your link:

```
<dl class="sub-nav" data-tab>
 <dd><a href="#all" id="all">All</a></dd>
</dl>
```

And add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document) .on('click', '#all', function(e) {
    $('.tabs-content div').addClass('active');
    $('#all').addClass('active');
  })
</script>
```

And if you are getting an error, add: `href="#all"` to your link.